# Почему наречие пишется так?

Tags: наречия

**

> Курить взатяг

**

Почему "взатяг" пишется слитно, если можно сказать "курить в полный затяг", "курить в самый затяг"?

Comment: в полную тягу вроде

Comment: Существительное "затяг" существует,  поэтому  наречие "взатяг" образовано от него.    Пожалуйста, будьте внимательны при приемке ответов. https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/затяг

Comment: Но речь не о существительном, а о наречии.

Comment: Курить в самый (полный) затяг, здесь затяг – существительное, но не наречие.  Обычный парный вариант, сравнить: сначала - с начала года.

Comment: А просто курить (в)затяг? Ведь способ проверки - это постановка определения.

Comment: Парные варианты. Этот способ проверки не дает однозначного результата.  Наверх - на самый верх.

Comment: Тогда на что же ориентироваться?

Comment: На падежное управление.  Курить (во что?) нельзя, можно курить (как?) Вероятно, курить в полный затяг  – это некорректное сочетание, оно не встречается в литературе.  Делаю (что?)  полный затяг, вот это верно.  Поэтому нормировали только наречие курить (как?) взатяг.

Comment: Один пример в корпусе все же есть.

Comment: Не в затяг?  https://kartaslov.ru/как-правильно-пишется-словосочетание/не+взатяг

Comment: Он курил заморскую ароматную штучку, как отечественную гродненскую “Астру”, — в полный затяг, весь дым в себя, в легкие.
 [Виктор Козько. «И никого, кто бы видел мой страх…» (1999) // «Дружба народов», 15.05.1999]

Comment: Тогда будем считать, что здесь парный вариант сущ. и наречие. Но вариант  встречается редко.  Обратим внимание на присоединение.  Сочетание не рядом с глаголом, неправильность может быть незаметной. Сравнить:  он курил сигарету в полный затяг.

Answer (score 0):

Это слово — разг. *взатя́г* — образовано от наречия ***взатя́жку*** и как подобное
должно писаться также в одно слово.